# API Gateway vs Web Servers

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, api-gateway, system-design

This question was asked from in recent system design interview. I got stumbled while explain the difference. In my design i created like that, client --> load balancers
--> worker nodes server and databases(server handling business logic and data stores).

Interviewer asked what do you know about web servers ? Will you be adding them here if yes/no why ?
I simply told them after using layer 4 load balancer and api gateway we will not be needing the web server. But was unable to provide the rationale behind it as i was not clear. Please provide some insights on actual use of web server in our design.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

let's clarify some terminology then.

A load balancer doesn't have any "smarts". It's a dumb service with the only purpose of re-routing requests. It can do some other things, but that's the core.

An API Gateway on the other hand has business logic knowledge. It is normally used to perform calls to underlying services and aggregate the results. It acts as a central orchestration point, hiding the backend complexity. It can also be used to perform different logic based on the client type (eg. desktop, mobile and so on).

Now, the question was *probably* around how many instances of the worker services you have. That depends on the count of requests and the type of work.
For example, if the work can be offloaded to the background using queues, you can probably use less workers, since you don't have to return an answer to the caller immediately.
The best action here, since you're doing an interview, is to ask more clarifying questions yourself, like

- what's the type of application?
- what kind of traffic are we going to serve?
- will there be peaks? (like black Friday for an e-commerce)
- do we have constraints on the infrastructure? (eg. vendor lock-in)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @David Guida said, Web servers help with handling request traffic and load balancing. Web server is an application that helps you with SSL offloading, network monitoring, and many other use cases.
You can load balance your traffic with DNS (IP base load balancing) but that's not recommended. There are scenarios that handle hard with DNS. For example, having logical health checks and moving the traffic between nodes is tougher with DNS.